# Pygame library - Sprites aren't rendering properly on the screen

Tags: python, macos, pygame, visual-glitch

When I'm using sprites in my pygame-based game they don't seem to work properly - as you can see on the screenshot they don't have the right shape and have some weird distortion in the upper part.

[Black squares have distortions on the top; sprite in the centre must be something like arrow-shaped.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlYo0.jpg)

Piece of code involved in loading images (copypasted right from pygame's tutorials):

```
def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
fullname = os.path.join('data', 'images')
fullname = os.path.join(fullname, name)
try:
    image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
except pygame.error as message:
    print('Cannot load image:', fullname)
    raise SystemExit(message)
image = image.convert()
if colorkey is not None:
    if colorkey is -1:
        colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
    image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
return image, image.get_rect()
```

I've been doing my project on Python 2.7.11 and 3.4.2 on Mac OS X and got this issue. But when I tested it on Python 3.1 on Windows, problem didn't show up and sprites loaded normally. So I think it's something about Mac OS X.

Comment: maybe use different image format gif, bmp, jpg, png

Comment: No, using different formats won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on El Capitan (OS X 10.11)?  If so, you are seeing a known bug in SDL_image on that version of OS X.  See this link for details and a possible workaround:

https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated

Comment: Thanks a lot, your link helped. So the solution is downgrading from SDL 1.2.12 to 1.2.10.